# Software to convert from jGRASP .java to .jar

Tags: java

I am trying to convert my .java file to .exe file, and I found a way to do that using launch4j. launch4j, though, requires a .jar file.

My question: What software should I use to convert my .java files to .jar? Also, I make java programs with jGRASP.

P.S. If You could give a walkthrough on how to use the software as well, I'd be grateful

Comment: Your title says java to jar, but your question says java to exe. Which is it?

Comment: Well, if there is a .java to .exe, I would love to know about it. But since I have only found .jar to .exe, I will have to find a .java to .jar converter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure this falls under software recommendations as much as software instruction, but since it seems fairly easy, I'll tell you what I found.

First of all, I simply googled "jgrasp to jar".
There are youtube links that claim to tell you how to create an executable jar, which may be what you want directly.  Personally, I HATE video instructions.  But if they work for you, they do exist.

The first actual link was a [walkthrough](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~luv/teaching/COMP110/createjar.html) showing how to use JGrasp to create a jar file.

I've never used JGrasp, so I'm not sure how helpful this will be, but it looked fairly thorough.

Again, as you are new, you may not be aware, but there is a good chance this question may get flagged as off topic, since you are asking how to use a program, not what program to use.  There are other Stack Exchange sites that are better for support.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Many Thanks! Also, sorry I am not asking the question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a Java compiler.

The [Oracle Java JDK](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) is the most popular tool to compile Java source code.

If you choose the Netbeans package, you can import your Java files, compile them, and then generate a JAR via the graphical user interface.

It is free. If you prefer open source, OpenJDK is mostly based on the same source code and can do the same.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. I think it is due to the fact I am using jGRASP .java files? Thanks anyways, it would probably work for other people's .java files.